# Swift MapKit - Annotations dont show in the MapView

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, geolocation, mapkit

I am trying to create a MapView using MapKit framework which looks for the current user location and displays restaurants nearby. However, when I am trying to show annotations then they don't show up.

I have tried printing (response.mapItems) to check if it works and the result is good because it prints information about some restaurants that were found in the console.

Therefore, I don't know why these are not annotated on the map.

Here is the code that I've made:

```
import UIKit
import MapKit
import CoreLocation

class RestaurantViewController: UIViewController, CLLocationManagerDelegate {

@IBOutlet weak var map: MKMapView!

let manager = CLLocationManager()

func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {

    let location = locations[0]

    let span:MKCoordinateSpan = MKCoordinateSpanMake(0.025, 0.025)
    let myLocation:CLLocationCoordinate2D = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(location.coordinate.latitude, location.coordinate.longitude)
    let region:MKCoordinateRegion = MKCoordinateRegionMake(myLocation, span)

    map.setRegion(region, animated: true)

    self.map.showsUserLocation = true
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    manager.delegate = self
    manager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
    manager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
    manager.startUpdatingLocation()

    let request = MKLocalSearchRequest()
    request.naturalLanguageQuery = "restaurant"

    request.region = map.region

    let search = MKLocalSearch(request: request)
    search.start { (response, error) in

        guard let response = response else {
            return
        }

        for item in response.mapItems {
            print(response.mapItems) - Console shows some restaunrant outputs that were correctly fetched
            let annotation = MKPointAnnotation()
            annotation.coordinate = item.placemark.coordinate
            annotation.title = item.name

            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.map.addAnnotation(annotation)
            }

        }

    }
}

}
```

Comment: The distance between response.mapItems and user location is separated?

Answer (score 1):

You annotation implementation is a little off, allow me to explain how it should be.

Adding annotations to your map relies on two things.

1. A class conforming to `MKAnnotation`.
2. A subclass of `MKAnnotationView`.

Your map has annotations added to it but it does not know how to show them, so it shows nothing. You can tell it how to show them by implementing `viewForAnimation`. Take a look at my example below:

```
class PinAnnotation: NSObject, MKAnnotation {

    var coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D

    init(coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D) {
        self.coordinate = coordinate
        super.init()
    }
}

class PinAnnotationView: MKAnnotationView {

    @available(*, unavailable)
    override init(annotation: MKAnnotation?, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
        super.init(annotation: annotation, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
    }

    @available(*, unavailable)
    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    }

    init(annotation: PinAnnotation) {
        super.init(annotation: annotation, reuseIdentifier: nil)

        self.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 30, height: 30)

        self.image = UIImage(named: "mypinimage") // or whatever.
    }
}
```

Here we have the definition for the two objects I spoke of above.

```
func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, viewFor annotation: MKAnnotation) -> MKAnnotationView? {
        if let imageAnnotation = annotation as? ImageAnnotation {
            let view = ImageAnnotationView(annotation: imageAnnotation)
            return view
        }

        return nil
    }
```

Here we have the implementation of `viewForAnnotation` that I spoke of above.

Answer (score 0):

Implement viewForAnnotation

```
   func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView,viewFor annotation: MKAnnotation) -> MKAnnotationView?
```

see my demo here [customPinAnnotationButton](https://github.com/ShKhan9/customPinAnnotationButton)

Comment: I'd like to ask how it will exactly work because I am not sure how to do it.